# Basic use of qtip2 with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, qtip2

I'm trying to use a tooltip from qtip2 inside an ng-repeater.

I'm using the simple title attribute:

```
$('[title!=""]').qtip();
```

qtips show in a regular item. However, they do not show within the angular repeater. Inspecting the elements, I can see it did replace the title with old title.

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/pewJYxbyBdMk5kqm01Bm?p=info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here is that you're binding qtip to elements that don't exist yet. Your best bet is to create a `qtip` directive that you can add to your elements and have the qtip() method ran after it's created.

Example:

```
// remove $('[title!=""]').qtip(); from top of js file
app.directive('qtip', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.qtip({ content: attrs.qtip});
    }
  };
});
```

Then in your html:

```
<span qtip="{{friend.gender}} ({{friend.age}} years old)"> [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}}</span>
```

[Updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KGVa0EHRDvAPQt8uicQh?p=preview).